# __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x

Help me please. Install scikit-learn not working

```
data_final_vars=data_final.columns.values.tolist()
y=['y']
X=[i for i in data_final_vars if i not in y]
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(logreg, 20)
rfe = rfe.fit(os_data_X, os_data_y.values.ravel())
print(rfe.support_)
print(rfe.ranking_)
```

Error in line 7: TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 16):

Try specifying that you're overriding a default parameter:

```
rfe = RFE(logreg, step = 20)
```

Answer (score 5):

To use RFE, first the class is configured with the chosen algorithm specified via the “estimator” argument and the number of features to select via the “n_features_to_select” argument.

Try

```
rfe = RFE(estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_features_to_select=20)
```

Comment: This solved the issue I was facing, the other answer doesn't work.
It's not working because of the change in sklearn 0.24. See official documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html